# animation of texts and images

Tags: android, animation, textview, imageview

I am trying to animate images (imageView) together with their associate text (textView).
I followed an advice I got here and used AsyncTask with handler to UI thread to dynamically change the images and text. This should be a simple code but the problem is that i get/see only the last image and text. in the case of the code below, only im2 (the second image) and t2 (the second text) will be shown.

can someone tell what the problem is?

my code goes like this:

```
    public class picshow extends Activity
{
    private static Integer[] Imgid = {R.drawable.im1, R.drawable.im2};
    private static Integer[] Strid = {R.string.t1, R.string.t2};

    private Handler handToUI = new Handler();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picView);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usertext);

        myTask task = new myTask();
        task.execute("nothing");
    }



    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String >
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params )
        {
             //Do noting and return a String. a preparation for future code
            return params[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( String result )
        {

            //send message to UI
            for(int i = 0;i<Strid.length;i++)
            {
                final int si = Strid[i];
                final int ii = Imgid[i];
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    handToUI.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picView);
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usertext);
                        public void run()
                        {
                            text.setText(si);
                            image.setImageResource(ii);
                        }
                    });
                 }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        }
    }

}
```

thanks
lipi

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have corrected your code

```
handToUI.post(new Runnable()
{
     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picView);
     TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usertext);
     public void run()
     {
          try
          {
              Thread.sleep(5000);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          text.setText(si);
          image.setImageResource(ii);
     }
});
```

I hope it is help you.